# generate random string based on regex. javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, random

Suppose you want a random string of a determined size based on a regex.

What a'm doing to solve the problem is this: First define a ***set*** of *'all possible'* characters, then choose randomly a char from it and see if matches regex, then do it again as many times as necesary until complete the random string.

One problem is, using this method could theorotically never complete.

Here's my code:

```js
var set=
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'+
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'+
    '0123456789'+
    'ºª\\!|"@·#$~%¦&¬/½(⅛)^=`\'?¯¿˘[`+]*´{¨ç}ÇñÑ.:,;-_<>«»¶¥ŧđ¢ħ£æø€åœð®þŋß¤×µ';
function randomString(size, regex){
    var i=0;
    text='';
    var length=set.length-1;
    while(i<size){
        var nth=Math.round(Math.random()*length);
        var ch=set.charAt(nth);
        if(ch.match(regex)){
            text+=ch;
            i++;
        }
    }       
    return text;
};
```

Are there some better approach?

Comment: May want to spend some time studying up on finite automata.  With a DFA derived from the regexp, this can be done efficiently.

Comment: you would want to cross off misses from a list of all possibilities, lest you repeatedly guess the same thing over and over... and what if the regexp is /\w{7,}/, how would it ever get to 7? you'de be better off parsing the regexp and finding smaller sub-sets that match first.